# nuxt component : computed vs data

Tags: vue-component, nuxt.js

In my nuxt component, I can't understand the difference between `computed` and `data`. I get the difference between `data` and `asyncData` but there is nothing regarding those two attributes.

```
<template>
  {{computedMessage}}
  {{dataMessage}}
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      computedMessage(){
        return this.$store.state.whatever;
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        dataMessage: "Hi there"
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

- If `data` is 100% static, then why make it a function?
- If I want to have `process.env` in the function, should it be in `computed` or in `data`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `computed` and `data` is **not** reactivity.  Both are fully reactive, as seen [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods).  The real difference between the two is essentially this:

- `data` is made up of [properties](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp)
- `computed` is made up of [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

They both serve very different purposes, but together give you some powerful tools for data manipulation.

For example:

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.adults)
  }
  data() {
    return {
      users: [
        { name: 'Jack', age: 12 },
        { name: 'Jill', age: 53 },
        { name: 'Smith', age: 29 },
        { name: 'Matt', age: 18 }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    adults() {
      return this.users.filter(user => user.age >= 18)
    }
  }
}
```

This example will return 3 users from `this.adults`: Jill, Smith, and Matt.  Without a `computed` property, you'd need to call a `method` to compute this, and you'd need to re-call it every single time you need to access that data again.

What's great about using `computed` properties is that their results are [cached](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods), similar to Vuex `getters`.  This can obviously have some huge benefits when working with larger data sets.

So in summary, `data` is used for storing data, and `computed` is used for calculating new results based on data without needing to change the original state.

So now to your points:

> If data is 100% static, then why make it a function?

This is because Vue shares references to all its properties, including `data`, between instances of the same component.  So instead of declaring a plain `data` object, we declare a function that returns a fresh version each time it's instantiated.

> If I want to have process.env in the function, should it be in computed or in data?

You're able to access process.env in either `computed` or `data`.  In general, if you have access to the Nuxt instance using `this`, then chances are you also have access to the `process.env` properties.

Answer (score -2):

Well the difference between `data` and `computed` is that computed is reactive and data is static. So if you want to use data that gets automatically updated, you have to use `computed`.

`computed`is for example often used when you have to wait for data (e.g. from REST api), but you don't want to block your UI. So you assign a `computed`variable and the part of your UI is updated when the data has arrived.

To understand, why `data` needs to be a function, you should have a look at [this](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-instancing).

Comment: This isn't correct.  Data in Vue is reactive. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

Comment: no, data is not reactive. If you want to change it, you have to change this explicit! The view reacts on changed data, but data itself is not reacting on changes...

Comment: That is not what reactive means in the context of Vuejs.  Reactive means that Vue will react to changes to the property.  It does not mean that the property will react to changes made to anything other than itself.  Indeed, computed properties only behave reactively when watching reactive properties.  Try returning a value like `Date.now()`, which is not reactive, from a computed property.  The timestamp will not change throughout the lifespan of the component, because computed properties cache their response, and only update due to reactivity.

Comment: See this link where they go over how reactive properties are declared: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.  Notice, they're talking specifically about `data`

Comment: computed sets a link to something. so calling it will give you the source.